# GitHub Api - List every file of a given folder using curl

Tags: curl, github-api

Actually I am able to connect to my GitHub and get content from a file with a given url:

> curl -s
>   https:// >access_token< @raw.githubusercontent.com/ >a/given/path< / >a_file<

**Question:**
What I would like te be able to do is with a curl call, have a response where every file name is listed. 
Something like:

> curl -s
>   https:// >access_token< @raw.githubusercontent.com/ >a/given/path<

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is three years old ... maybe it will help someone.

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH
```

If your PATH is a directory, the command above will return all files in this directory.
For more information: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents